# ¿Cómo insertar edad a partir de fecha de nacimiento en SQL?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, date, select

Tengo un registro donde el usuario inserta su fecha de nacimiento. En una tabla se recoge el campo 'fecha' y en otro campo 'edad'.

Este SELECT funciona y calcula la edad en SQL pero no sé como pasarlo al campo 'edad':

```
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(fecha) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5) < RIGHT(fecha,5)) AS edad 
FROM tabla;
```

¿Se puede insertar directamente con SQL o hay que hacerlo con PHP? 
Agradeceré cualquier ayuda

---

Ok, si no se debe calcular la edad en la BD, entonces la calculo con una función en PHP. 
Mi pregunta es;  Una vez tengo calculado el valor, lo paso en la variable $edad, y  a partir de aqui quiero pasarlo en un campo 'edad' de la BD. (lo necesito para un buscador según 'edad')

He probado un UPDATE pero no actualiza. Es correcto asi?

```html
        <!-- Page Content -->
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12" style="left:5%;">

               <div class="row">
                   <div class="gallery col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE edad BETWEEN 18 AND 20 ORDER BY id DESC"; 
      $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
          if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado))
          {
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
           { 
           $fecha= $row['fecha'];
           $id = $row['id'];
           
           
      $edad = calcular_edad($fecha);
            
            if (isset($edad)) {
         $sql4 = "UPDATE alumnos SET edad=$edad WHERE id = $id";
        
    } ?> 
            
     <div>
    <a href="alumno.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" target="_blank"><img  style="display:block;"  src="<?php echo $row['avatar']; ?>" alt=""/></a>

          <div class="caption" style=" position:absolute; top:85%; width:100%; height:15%; background-color:black;opacity:0.8;">
              
      <div style="z-index:2;">
               <h4 style="margin-left:40%;color:white;float:left;"><?php echo 
                $row['nombre']; ?><span>,&nbsp;</span></h4>
               
      <h4  style="padding-top:10px;margin-left:20%;color:white;" ><?php echo $edad; ?></h4>
      </div>
     </div>

    <?php }
    } ?>

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        
      
    </body>
```

Comment: No deberías tener ambos campos en tu tabla, eso no es normalizado. Lo correcto es calcular la edad cuando lo necesitas.

Comment: Como te indica el compañero no se recomienda tener campos calculados en las tablas, y aun que existen algunos casos en los que se debe romper la normalización de los datos no creo que este sea uno de ellos.

Comment: Exacto... en una base de datos con millones de personas, mantener actualizada la edad de cada una en la base de datos podría terminar siendo algo terrible en cuanto al rendimiento y en cuanto a todo. Ese tipo de campos se calcula al extraerlo de la base de datos y sólo si se necesita.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios,  entonces hay que hacer una función con PHP? de todas formas la BD es pequeñita,  si  alguien me diera una respuesta concreta mejor

Comment: ¿Te sirvió algunas de las respuestas que te proporcionamos?

Answer (score 1):

como ya te recomendaron mis compañeros no es una buena practica poner campos como edad en una base de datos, ese tipo de valores los puedes obtener mediante PHP de manera precisa cuando lo necesites.

En tu caso te recomiendo solo almacenar la fecha de nacimiento del usuario o persona.

Script:

```
<?php
    $fecha_nacimiento = new DateTime("1982-06-03");
    $hoy = new DateTime();
    $edad = $hoy->diff($fecha_nacimiento);
    echo $edad->y;
?>
```

**Mini explicación del script**

Usando la funcion `diff` de PHP puedes obtener la diferencia entre dos objetos DateTimeInterface.

Otro ejemplo mediante una funcion:

```
function calcular_edad($fecha){
    $dias = explode("-", $fecha, 3);
    $dias = mktime(0,0,0,$dias[1],$dias[0],$dias[2]);
    $edad = (int)((time()-$dias)/31556926 );
    return $edad;
}
// Formato: dd-mm-yy
echo calcular_edad("01-10-1989");
```

Existen bastantes maneras de calcular la edad, mediante funciones, condicionales, calculos, etc...

Comment: Gracias por las funciones. Una vez tengo la variable $edad, quiero pasar los valores en un campo 'edad' de la BD. (la necesito para un buscador según 'edad' ) He probado un UPDATE pero no actualiza. Es correcto asi?  debajo dejo el código

Comment: Hola, no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta compañera, redactala nuevamente, estare pendiente para ayudarte.

Comment: Disculpa quizás no me expresé bien . Reformulé la pregunta en este enlace. .Espero tu amable respuesta. https://goo.gl/bVKjjn

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario que obtengas uno a uno los alumnos para calcular su edad y guardarla en la base de datos. Con una única consulta podrás actualizar la edad de todos los alumnos de la tabla:

```
UPDATE alumnos
SET
  edad =
    YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(fecha) -
    (RIGHT(CURDATE(), 5) < RIGHT(fecha, 5))
```

[Aquí puedes ver el resultado en línea](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/189b3/1).

El funcionamiento es el siguiente:

- Resto al año actual el año de nacimiento.
- Si los últimos 5 caracteres de la fecha (mes y día) son inferiores a los de la fecha actual (aún no ha llegado la fecha del cumpleaños), resto un año más.

Aún así, puedes prescindir completamente del campo `edad` en la tabla. No necesitas para nada un campo en la base de datos con la edad de los alumnos ya que puedes calcularla al vuelo en todo momento tal y como tú mismo has planteado en la pregunta:

```
SELECT
  *,
  YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(fecha) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(), 5) < RIGHT(fecha, 5)) edad
FROM alumnos
```

[Aquí puedes ver el resultado en línea](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1345c7/2).

Si quieres limitar por edad entonces deberás agregar la función al `WHERE`. No te preocupes que el optimizador de consultas evitará que se calcule dos veces la edad por cada alumno:

```
SELECT
  *,
  YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(fecha) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(), 5) < RIGHT(fecha, 5)) edad
FROM alumnos
WHERE
  YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(fecha) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(), 5) < RIGHT(fecha, 5)) BETWEEN 8 AND 11
```

[Aquí puedes ver el resultado en línea](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1345c7/7).

Si no te gusta repetir la función siempre puedes hacer uso de [`HAVING` en vez de `WHERE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html):

```
SELECT
  *,
  YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(fecha) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(), 5) < RIGHT(fecha, 5)) edad
FROM alumnos
HAVING edad BETWEEN 8 AND 11
```

[Aquí puedes ver el resultado en línea](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1345c7/8).

---

Por otro lado, el problema que tienes con tu código PHP es que asignas a una variable el SQL que quieres hacer, pero no lo envías al servidor MySQL nunca, por lo que nunca se actualizan las edades como esperabas hacer:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE edad BETWEEN 18 AND 20 ORDER BY id DESC"; 
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $fecha = $row['fecha'];
    /* Mucho ojo con la inyección SQL */
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $row['id']);
    $edad = calcular_edad($fecha);
    /* $edad SIEMPRE va a estar definido, lo haces en la línea anterior.
        Es mejor actualizar si la edad ha cambiado. */
    if ($edad != $row['edad'])) {
        $sql4 = "UPDATE alumnos SET edad=$edad WHERE id = $id";
        /* Ahora es importante que envíes la consulta al servidor: */
        $actualizacion = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql4);
    }
}
```