# Cómo hacer UPDATE en BD si el valor viene de una función de PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, formularios

En un formulario el usuario ingresa su fecha de nacimiento y en la BD se recoge el campo 'fecha'(tipo DATE) y en otro campo 'edad' (tipo int(2)) .
Una función en PHP calcula la edad desde 'fecha' y una vez calculada en años la paso en la variable $edad. 
A partir de aqui simplemente quiero actualizar en un campo 'edad' de la BD , ya que el campo fecha de nacimiento está formato YYYY/MM/DD  Necesito este campo edad para un simple buscador por edades.

He probado un UPDATE pero no actualiza, falta algo en el codigo quizás?  Es correcto tal como está?
Gracias de antemano a quien responda.

```
CREATE TABLE `alumnos` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `edad` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```html
<!-- Page Content -->
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12" style="left:5%;">

               <div class="row">
                   <div class="gallery col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                   
 <!-- SELECT ENTRE FECHAS PARA MOSTRAR RANGO DE EDADES-->        
 <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE fecha BETWEEN 1990/01/01 AND 1999/01/01 ORDER BY id DESC";
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE edad BETWEEN 18 AND 23 ORDER BY id DESC"; 
    $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
           { 
    $fecha= $row['fecha'];
    $id = $row['id'];
      
function CalculaEdad( $fecha ) {
    global $fecha;
    list($Y,$m,$d) = explode("-",$fecha);
    return( date("md") < $m.$d ? date("Y")-$Y-1 : date("Y")-$Y );
    }     
           
      $edad = CalculaEdad($fecha);
            
            //if (isset($edad)) {
         //$sql4 = "UPDATE alumnos SET edad=$edad WHERE id = $id";
        
    } ?> 
            
     <div>
    <a href="alumno.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" target="_blank"><img  style="display:block;"  src="<?php echo $row['avatar']; ?>" alt=""/></a>

          <div class="caption" style=" position:absolute; top:85%; width:100%; height:15%; background-color:black;opacity:0.8;">
              
      <div style="z-index:2;">
               <h4 style="margin-left:40%;color:white;float:left;"><?php echo 
                $row['nombre']; ?><span>,&nbsp;</span></h4>
               
      <h4  style="padding-top:10px;margin-left:20%;color:white;" ><?php echo $edad; ?></h4>
      </div>
     </div>

    <?php }
    } ?>

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        
      
    </body>
   
   
 <!-- INPUT DEL FORMULARIO PARA LA FECHA DE NACIMIENTO Y EDAD-->
  
<div  class="form-group"><br/>
   <label for="nombre" class="col-md-3 control-label" style="color:#F3E2A9;">
  </label>
  <div style="color:#F3E2A9;" class="col-md-9">fecha
  <input style="width:150px;" type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" required  >
   </div>
</div>

<div  class="form-group"><br/>
 <label for="nombre" class="col-md-3 control-label" style="color:#F3E2A9;">
 </label>
  <div style="color:#F3E2A9;" class="col-md-9">Edad
  <input style="width:20px;" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="edad" 
  maxlength ="2"   >
 </div>
</div>
              
  <!-- ARCHIVO PHP QUE RECBE LA EDAD Y HACE UPDATE EN LA BD (NO FUNCIONA) -->
 <?php
$edad = $_GET['edad'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

  if (isset($edad)) {
            $sql = "UPDATE chicas SET edad= '$edad' WHERE id = '$id';";
}
?>
```

Comment: No puedes meter una edad en un campo tipo date, tienes que cambiar el tipo en tu bd

Comment: Porque no? La fecha de nacimiento se introduce con un input tipo date y se almacena en la BD tipo DATE y no hay problema, calcula las edades en años perfecto. El problema esté en el UPDATE, no deja insertar el valor en el campo 'edad' de tipo int(2) . Mirate el codigo por favor,  no ves algun fallo?

Comment: Hola amiga, podrias subir la estructura de tu base de datos :)

Comment: Hola. El otro dia hiciste una pregunta muy similar. Es la misma?? estan relacionadas? Tambien tienes montones de preguntas sin respuestas aceptadas. ES MUY IMPORTANTE QUE LEAS [tour] para saber como funcionamos. donde estas ejecutando el update?

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque sólo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855)

Comment: Haz caso de lo que ya te recomendamos [en esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114697/29967). Es una **pésima y horrible práctica** querer almacenar la edad en una base de datos. Primero, porque sería un duplicado implícito de otra posible columna que es la fecha de nacimiento, segundo porque la edad es algo relativo... sí relativo. Imagina que quieras saber la edad a la que te casaste... la edad a la que te jubilaste, la edad que tenías cuando nació tu primer hijo... en ninguno de esos casos una columna calculada `edad` serviría para nada. Aparte de lo que supondría actualizarla

Comment: se podrian actualizar la columna edad mediante un cron sin embargo como te mencionan mis compañeros es una muy mala practica, la edad la puedes utilizar mediante PHP cuando necesites visualizarla, sin embargo el campo edad en una db no es util, el campo fecha de nacimiento ese si es muy importante para poder visualizar la edad actual del usuario. por cierto jaja viste que usaste mi script pero no me dejaste punticos jajaj

Comment: A. Cedano, gbianchi: OK, intentaré tener buenas prácticas, es que soy nueva aquí! ;)  En cuanto la edad, entendí que no se aconseja guardarla en BD para evitar el calculos inecesarios eso está claro. A ver, la idea es hacer un simple buscador por edades.   Entonces si se hace SELECT de la fecha de nacimiento hay que poner en formato yyyy/mm/dd?  el rango  BETWEEN como queda?   corrijo el codigo arriba

Comment: ByGroxD: sin problema, dime como darte los puntos 
Dejo la estructura de la BD por si ves algo.

Comment: Maria: se te recomender mirar [tour] varias veces, lo hiciste? ahi dice como funciona el sitio, como se espera que se comporten los usuarios, como funciona la reputacion, y siempre se debe tratar de conseguir una respuesta correcta a las preguntas. Ninguna de tus preguntas tiene una respuesta correcta marcada. Esto es porque no les hiciste seguimiento, o porque te las contestaron y no las marcaste como correctas. Si las preguntas no tienen respuesta o no sirven, borralas. Si tienen respuestas correctas, marcalas como correctas.

Comment: Ya miré pero no encuentro lo de marcar pregunta correcta.

Comment: Maria, hay un tilde a la izquierda de la respuesta, debajo del puntaje de la misma, que permite aceptar la respuesta como correcta. eso esta descripto al principio del [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez te ayude esto, realmente no entiendo claramente lo que quiere hacer. Según tu consulta obtienes la **fecha de nacimiento** y la utilizas para poder calcular la **edad**, al obtener la edad puedes realizar una consulta con el `UPDATE` a la BD, como podrás darte cuenta, ahí agrego unas **comillas simples** para poder utilizar las `$variables` de PHP dentro de la consulta, prueba así. Si es que no funciona, podrías apoyarte de **otro archivo PHP**, el primero obtiene la edad y manda el valor de esa variable al segundo archivo a través de `$_GET`, el segundo toma el valor y ejecuta el `UPDATE`.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE fecha BETWEEN 1990/01/01 AND 1999/01/01 ORDER BY id DESC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado)){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
    {
        $fecha= $row['fecha'];
        $id = $row['id'];

        function CalculaEdad( $fecha ) {
            global $fecha;
            list($Y,$m,$d) = explode("-",$fecha);
            return( date("md") < $m.$d ? date("Y")-$Y-1 : date("Y")-$Y );
        }                                       
        $edad = CalculaEdad($fecha);
        //Elije una opción, esta
        if (isset($edad)) {
            $sql4 = "UPDATE alumnos SET edad='$edad' WHERE id = '$id';";
        }
        //O esta. RECUERDA COMENTAR ALGUNA DE LAS DOS.
        if (isset($edad)) {
            header('Location: agregaredad.php?edad='.$edad.'&id='.$id);
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. No funcionó ninguna de las 2 opciones. La idea es bien simple; seleccionar un rango de edades y mostrar paginas por rangos de edades, de 18-19, 20-21.. Al principio hay un SELECT de la fecha de nacimiento en formato yyyy/mm/dd  y está el BETWEEN para el rango de fecha. Luego la función calcula la edad en años y va bien.  El UPDATE es para pasar esta cifra en años a la BD, pero me graba valor '0'  en la columna 'edad' , quizás sea la BD?  Ya otros compañeros recomiendan dejar la opción del UPDATE y hacer el calculo en PHP directo. A partir de aqui no sé que hacer.

Comment: Es que como muchos te comentan el agregar un campo de edad en la BD es no es una buena práctica ya que la edad es relativa, por ejemplo en 2017 tienes 20 años, el año siguiente 21, y habría que actualizar la base de datos cada que ese usuario cumpla años, en cambio puedes guardar su fecha de nacimiento y hacer un calculo de los años cumplidos, y de ahí hacer un filtro de las personas con cierto rango.

Comment: Entiendo no es buena practica guardar la edad en una BD. Entonces si guardo la fecha en formato yyyy/mm/dd , habrá que seleccionar un rango de fechas, no? . Con la sentencia SELECT de arriba no funciona.  Tienes alguna idea como seleccionar un rango de edades y mostrar los resultados?